# Type casting msg.value to uint248

Tags: solidity, integers, data-types

I am new to solidity programming and sorry if my question is very basic.

I am wondering if we can cast msg.value to uint248

Example below ;
uint value;
 value = (uint248) (msg.value);

Comment: Why do you want to cast to `uint248`? Generally it is more efficient to leave it as a `uint256`

Answer (score 6):

For casting, use `value = uint248(msg.value);`

Casting to save 8 bits in this case is not worth it and will probably cost more gas due to unpacking: see [Why does uint8 cost more gas than uint256?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/why-does-uint8-cost-more-gas-than-uint256)

Even when using a struct of uint248 and uint8, it is best to actually test whether you are getting some gas savings.

Comment: Is it bad practice to use uin248 for holding balance? I usually see balance stored with type uint.

Comment: @AdamSoffer Yes, unless you have another state variable that is uint8 and can use the unused 8 bits "next" to the uint248, there is no benefit to using uint248 for storing a balance.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple example to demonstrate casting `msg.value` to a `uint248` value using [Browser Solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) with the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Test {
    uint248 public value;

    function Test() {
        value = 123;
    }

    function () payable {
        value = uint248(msg.value);
    }
}
```

The screen below shows the deployment of the code to the JavaScript VM:

[image]

I've set the **Value** field to 456.789 and clicked on the **(fallback)** function, simulating the sending of 456.789 ETH to the contract:

[image]

I've set the **Value** field back to 0 and clicked on the **value** button to show that the `msg.value` of 456.789 ETH was casted to a `uint248` field:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I learned both casting and how to use Solidity browser for debugging .

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `value = uint248(msg.value);`