# How to store negative values inside {8||16||32} bits in populus?

Tags: solidity, populus, integers

I want to store `-1` in smallest memory such as in {8||16||32} bits instead of 256 bits.

```
int i = -1;
```

When I return `var`, it returns
`-1L` instead of `-1`.

I have assigned `-1` into a `int8` variable. As I know `int8` is signed integer.

```
int8 i = -1;
```

But when I return `output`, it returns: '115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639679L' instead of `-1`.

[Q] What should I do to obtain `-1`?

Please note that I have experimented this problem in `populus`:

As contract I have use @RichardHorrocks's contract: `NumTest` on the answer.

test.py:

```
def test_receipt(web3, accounts, chain, unmigrated_chain):
    my_contract       = unmigrated_chain.get_contract('NumTest');

    set_txn_hash     = my_contract.transact().NumTest();
    contract_address = unmigrated_chain.wait.for_receipt(set_txn_hash)

    output           = my_contract.call().number();
    print(output);
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Solved guidance: https://github.com/pipermerriam/populus/issues/250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code returns `-1` for me (for both `int8` and `int`):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract NumTest {

    int8 i;

    function NumTest() {
        i = -1;
    }

    function number() constant returns (int8 num) {
        return i;    
    }
}
```

As has been mentioned in previous threads, due to [unpacking costs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12259/52), the `int8` case (278 gas) is actually more expensive than the default `int`/`int256` case (224 gas).

For the above code, and for completeness (and because I was interested):

```
integer bits | gas cost
-------------+---------
     8       |   278
    16       |   278
    32       |   278
    64       |   278
   128       |   278
   248       |   278
   256       |   224
```

So unpacking costs are the same for anything below the optimal size.

Comment: I am very sorry related to I did not mention that I experienced this problem in `populus` and since it was not working in `populus`, I assumed it will not work in real blockchain environment. I guess the problem may related to `python` or `populus` I guess. I have updated my question with my test case.@RichardHorrocks

Comment: Ah, okay - thanks for adding the extra details. I'll leave my answer in case it's of use to anyone else, though I realise it doesn't answer your specific question anymore!