# Initialize a fixed size, 2 dimensional array within function

Tags: solidity, arrays

In Solidity, how do I define a fixed size, 2 dimensional uint8 array scoped to a function, initialized with all zeros?

E.g.

```
func(){
  var myArr = new uint8[5][5](); // which does not work.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using [the `memory` keyword](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays):

`uint8[4][2] memory myArr;`

`myArr` will then return the default value `uint8(0)` for all indices.

It should also be noted, that in Solidity array size is defined in reverse lookup order.
The last number in `myArr` would thus be `uint[1][3]`.

Also, in `memory` Arrays, `uint8` may actually be more costly than just using `uint256`, since the latter is [used internally](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3071/10387).

Answer (score 6):

Declaring an array inside a function is allocating a Memory Array which is different than storage array. [Source](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays)

`new` is used to declare variable sized array so I would do

```
function getValue(uint8 x, uint8 y) constant returns (uint8) {
    var length = 5;
    uint8[5][5] memory myArr;
    for (uint i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (uint j = 0; j < length; j++)
            myArr[i][j] = 0;

    return myArr[x][y];
}
```

You can test this on [Remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) to see that it works

Comment: So if I wanted to have an array uint8[256][256] I would have to type 65536 zeros?

Comment: Ah, but your link is helpful. It seems `uint8[5][5] memory myArr;` might do the trick.

Comment: Well I had weird issue when trying to do a loop to initialize it. But I'm pretty sure it is possible to do so.

Comment: @Jasper I edited my post to initialise array with loops