# What uint type should be declared for unix timestamps?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging, testing

I try to specify uint type to uint16 instead of just doing uint or uint256 when dealing with time stamps but it says that I must use at least uint24. It works with uint24, but shouldn't uint16 be plenty enough?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not really an answer to what you're asking, but...

Decreasing the size of a `uint` to less that 256 bits will increase the associated gas costs, not decrease it like you might be expecting. It'll be best to leave it as a `uint256`.

See: 
[Why does uint8 cost more gas than uint256?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/why-does-uint8-cost-more-gas-than-uint256)

---

**Edit:**

Noting that timestamps are the number of seconds since the Unix epoch:

- `uint16` maximum value = 65536 -> 01/01/1970 @ 6:12pm (UTC)
- `uint24` maximum value = 16777216 -> 07/14/1970 @ 4:20am (UTC)

So these values are too small.

Calling [`block.timestamp`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=timestamp#block-and-transaction-properties) (or `now`) currently returns `1508618011`, which is `0b1011001111010111010111100011011`. This requires 31 bits. So you're looking at least at a `uint32`, but more if you want to be future-proof.

Comment: What if we were talking about something that would be saved to storage? I assume it would be best practices to forexample use uint8 instead of uint256 for decimals, saving gas costs too.

Comment: Yep, true for variables written to storage - writing smaller quantities is cheaper. You'll want to experiment depending on how you're using the timestamps.

Comment: Storage is written in blocks of 32 bytes. Using smaller values is not cheaper

Comment: Okay, didn't know the block size - what Tjaden said :-)

Comment: so there is no difference declaring uint8 and uint32? gas wise? 
Does the same count for bytes?

Comment: `uint32` is more than enough, in my opinion: `2^32 - 1` equals to `4294967295`, i.e. `Sun Feb 07 2106`. None of us will probably be alive at that time, and I highly doubt Solidity will still be used to write distributed applications :)

Comment: When storing in a struct, they are lined up on 32 byte blocks, so you can fit multiple uint32s in a struct and save on storage costs big time...

Comment: Famous last words @skozin :)

Comment: Not only in structs, but generally when you define multiple storage variables one after another, solidity will attempt to do compact storage, meaning that it will attempt to store multiple variables in the same 32byte word.

That means that from the following example, the first is more gas efficient:
uint48 variable1
uint48 variabel2
uint256 variable

than:

uint48 variable1
uint256 variable2
uint48 variable3

Comment: @skozin 's remark misses a critical point: deployed contracts do not care about the language they were written in, and could continue running after 2106. It's all about if Ethereum and the EVM are still running then (or some modified version of them).

Answer (score 1):

According to Solidity docs `block.timestamp` is a `uint` which is an alias for `unit256`

`block.timestamp (uint): current block timestamp`

So I personally will use the same in case Solidity still around in Year 33658 :)

[Docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#global-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers aren't helping to clearly assess when to use the default `uint256` or a smaller `uintN`. I'll give it a try.

There are two parts:

### Can your code benefit from tight packing?

(Tested with `solc` 0.8.15)

Tight packing provides clear gains (gas savings) if your code is regularly writing the tightly packed variables to storage *together*. For example:

```
contract A {
    uint128 tightPacked1;
    uint128 tightPacked2;

    function writeBoth(uint128 tp1, uint128 tp2) public {
        tightPacked1 = tp1;
        tightPacked2 = tp2;
    }
}
```

But if your code isn't writing these variables together, there are no gains from tight packing. More, there are even losses compared to the `uint256` version because of downscaling as mentioned by Richard Horrocks (observed approx 2100 gas usage increase per write for non-0 numbers). For example:

```
contract A {
    uint128 tightPacked1;
    uint128 tightPacked2;

    function write1(uint128 tp1) public {
        tightPacked1 = tp1;
    }

    function write2(uint128 tp1) public {
        tightPacked2 = tp2;
    }
}
```

Last, if doing very few writes to storage (for example only in the contract constructor), you have to compare tight packing saving with increased costs due to notably downscaling.

In any case, use a tool to test gas costs of your functions in different scenarios.

### Which `uintN` to use

If tight packing is a good idea, you can look into picking the smallest `uintN` that does the job.

For a timestamp, `uint32` can be enough (2106 max). But for time durations, you can go much lower (for example `uint24` can do 6 months).