# Why time values should be used as uint256?

Tags: solidity, gas, storage, timestamp

Is there a reason to use the time value as `uint256`?
Is not `uint128` enough?
UnixTime...

Comment: you mean in solidity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 parts to consider: reading and storing.

For reading, the EVM is based on a word (storage slot) size of 256 bits, and that's why often it costs less gas when using `uint256`.  Example: [Why does uint8 cost more gas than uint256?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/why-does-uint8-cost-more-gas-than-uint256)

But if your contract is storing many timestamps, it can save gas to use `uint128` so that you can store 2 of them in 1 storage slot.  If you want to save half of the storage, don't forget to test to make sure you are correctly saving 2 `uint128` in 1 storage slot.