# Store constants as non-256 bit fields

Tags: solidity, gas-limit, uint256

My contract has a lot of `uint256` constant fields that are later used for various calculations. I am close to reaching the maximum allowed contract size and I am looking for optimizations.

I see that having some fields as `uint8` instead of `uint256` reduces size of the bytecode but at the same time, knowing that for `uint8` [operations need to downscale and cost more gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/why-does-uint8-cost-more-gas-than-uint256) I don't want to trade contract bytecode size and the cost of deployment paid once for more expensive day-to-day contract function calls.

Is there any solution allowing storing smaller fields in non 256-bit slots and not paying the cost of downscaling later, during every single operation using those fields?

Comment: In my experience constants are not much of a problem when optimizations are enabled in the compiler. I'd suggest to remove unneeded functions, using libraries, or splitting functionality in several contracts.