# Testing Error thrown with hardhat

Tags: ether, mocha, hardhat

How would you test the following function with solidity v0.7 and hardhat v2.3.3?

```
function myFunction(int8 _num) public {
        require(_num > 5, "Num should be bigger than 5");
        ...
}
```

I've tried:

```
try {
         await contract.myFunction(3);
} catch(error) {
         expect(error).to.equals("Num should be bigger than 5");
};
```

And also:

```
expect.fail(await contract.myFunction(3));
```

But I always get:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Num should be bigger than 5
```

Which seems to me the Virtual Machine breaking off with the test failing in the spot, without even having the chance to catch the error.

Comment: why are you using int8 and not just int?

Comment: possible values for that var are 1, 2 and 3 @MajdTL. That's why I'm using int8. Not sure it would safe gas, thou. I did not research that.

Comment: no it will cost you more gas, because the default is int and you changing it to int8

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/why-does-uint8-cost-more-gas-than-uint256

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When I test a function for revert I do the following in my javascript test file (e.g. myContractTest.js):

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
const { BigNumber } = require('ethers');

describe('Test contract', () => {
    it('deploy the smart contract and reverts', async () => {
        const MyContract = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyContract');
        const contractInstance = await MyContract.deploy(<add something if you have parameters in the constructor>);
        await expect(contractInstance.myFunction(BigNumber.from('6')))
        .to.be.revertedWith('Num should be bigger than 5');
    });
});
```

Then Run

```
npx hardhat test --network hardhat ./test/myContractTest.js
```

Documentation here: https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html#revert-with-message

Comment: thanks @Majd TL, but that still crashes the VM. Same error. 
Btw, not sure I mentioned it, but it's an async function.

Comment: @ntonnelier which solidity version are you using , and which hardhat version. are you changing a state inside that function or it is just a call data function?

Comment: it's a payable function and it changes data in storage (although after the require that throws the error here). I'm using solidity 0.7 and hardhat 2.3.3 @MajdTL

Comment: and you dont get any error when testing that in remix?

Comment: I updated my answer there was an error in the message idk if you noticed it. @ntonnelier

Comment: this made it @Majd TL. Just needed to correct to.revertedWith to to.be.revertedWith.
Thanks!

Comment: okay it works for me without "be", but anyway great accept it as answer please:)

Comment: `to.be.reverted` also works if you don't know the thrown error message